# What is the CoreData type that can be used for saving CKServerChangeToken?

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have an entity in CoreData called "ServerToken" that has two attributes zoneName and token. In the token attribute, I plan to store the CKServerChangeToken object. I plan to use the CKServerChangeToken for retrieving incremental changes from CloudKit. Can someone throw some light on... What type should be set for the token attribute to be able to store the CKServerChangeToken object?

Note: This question is not a duplicate of the below so question. The answer in the below link uses UserDefaults and I intend to use CoreData for saving the CKServerChangeToken.

[Save CKServerChangeToken to Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589140/save-ckserverchangetoken-to-core-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use transformable core data type, by which you can define your desired type in the NSManagedObject custom class.

See this related thread:

[How to save Array to CoreData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825604/how-to-save-array-to-coredata)