# Error trying to save CKServerChangeToken to UserDefaults

Tags: swift, cloudkit, beta, xcode11

Following the answer here:
[Save CKServerChangeToken to Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589140/save-ckserverchangetoken-to-core-data)

The code fails when I try to save the new token to user defaults.

I get the error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.__NSSwiftData' (0x1dad7a900) to 'CKServerChangeToken' (0x1da7fae08).
2019-07-28 12:05:41.594726-0700 HintApp[20235:1921952] Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.__NSSwiftData' (0x1dad7a900) to 'CKServerChangeToken' (0x1da7fae08).
```

- just saving the CKServerChangeToken as an Any to user defaults.

```
public extension UserDefaults {

    var serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken? {
        get {
            guard let data = self.value(forKey: changeTokenKey) as? Data else {
                return nil
            }

            let token: CKServerChangeToken?
            do {
                token = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: CKServerChangeToken.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                token = nil
            }

            return token
        }

        set {
            if let token = newValue {
                do {
                    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: token, requiringSecureCoding: true)
                    self.set(data, forKey: changeTokenKey)
                } catch {
                    // handle error
                    print("error setting change token:\(error)")
                }
            } else {
                self.removeObject(forKey: changeTokenKey)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
func fetchDatabaseChanges(database: CKDatabase, databaseTokenKey: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        var changedZoneIDs: [CKRecordZone.ID] = []

        let changeToken = UserDefaults.standard.serverChangeToken

        let operation = CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: changeToken)

        operation.recordZoneWithIDChangedBlock = { (zoneID) in
            changedZoneIDs.append(zoneID)
        }

        operation.recordZoneWithIDWasDeletedBlock = { (zoneID) in
            // Write this zone deletion to memory
        }

        operation.changeTokenUpdatedBlock = { (token) in
            // Flush zone deletions for this database to disk
            // Write this new database change token to memory
            print("saving new token \(token)")

            UserDefaults.standard.serverChangeToken = token
        }

        operation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock = { (token, moreComing, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error during fetch shared database changes operation", error)
                completion()
                return
            }
            // Flush zone deletions for this database to disk
            // Write this new database change token to memory

            self.fetchZoneChanges(database: database, databaseTokenKey: databaseTokenKey, zoneIDs: changedZoneIDs) {
                // Flush in-memory database change token to disk
                completion()
            }
        }
        operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
        database.add(operation)

    }
```

outcome:

```
saving new token <CKServerChangeToken: 0x2834ecf90; data=REDACTED==>
Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.__NSSwiftData' (0x1dad7a900) to 'CKServerChangeToken' (0x1da7fae08).
2019-07-28 12:05:41.594726-0700 HintApp[20235:1921952] Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.__NSSwiftData' (0x1dad7a900) to 'CKServerChangeToken' (0x1da7fae08).
```

**REDACTED contains actual data I don't want to share on here. Unrelated to my error.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's this one: 
````
UserDefaults.standard.serverChangeToken = token
````

Comment: huh. I was wrong. that line seems to be working. Hang on...lemme try and find it.

Comment: Unrelated but this is very cumbersome code. If you are going to extend `UserDefaults` write methods `func set(token : CKServerChangeToken, forKey key : String)` and `func token(for key : String) -> CKServerChangeToken?`. The bodies can be accomplished in two lines each.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry. I'm an idiot. A bit further down I was trying to pull CKServerChangeToken right out of userDefaults directly. I changed it to use the extension and it made it past that and is now cheerfully presenting me with error fetching zone change messages, which should go in a new question.